# Nestjs - Implement Azure-Ad Passport Authentication

Tags: azure, authentication, nestjs, passport.js, passport-azure-ad

How can I implement Azure-Ad Passport Authentication? Can't find any documentation for it, and read online that there are problems with that.

Comment: refer this https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-azure-ad/

Comment: There's not any explanation about how to implement in nestjs with guards :(

Answer (score 6):

Use MSAL for FrontEnd.
For Backend use Passport and [passport-azure-ad](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-azure-ad) npm.
[image]

- Then, you should create your app in Azure AD
- then, get tenantId and
  appId from app settings page,
- then, use code like that to get access
  token and check user auth.

// my auth-guard.ts

```
import { AuthGuard, PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { BearerStrategy } from 'passport-azure-ad';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';


@Injectable()
export class AzureADStrategy extends PassportStrategy(
  BearerStrategy,
  'azure-ad',
) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      identityMetadata: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantID}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`,
      clientID,
    });
  }

  async validate(data) {
    return data;
  }
}

export const AzureADGuard = AuthGuard('azure-ad');

// app.controller.ts

  @UseGuards(AzureADGuard)
  @Get('/api')
  get_api(): string {
    return 'OK';
  }
}
```

try it should work.

Comment: how can I add an on error handler to this solution?

Comment: Should I provide the custom strategy somewhere ? What if I'm not using modules ?